# Why does TP-LINK router speed slows down

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I have a TP-LINK WR841N router and a 100 MB connection.
For about 1-2 weeks my speed has dropped to 50-60 MB when I'm connected Wi-Fi or through a cable to the router.

If I plug the ISP cable direct in my laptop I have a speed of above 90 MB. So the problem must be with the router. Until now I have tried to reboot the router, reset router, restore to factory settings, update to latest firmware with no effect. After doing all of this I used `http://www.speedtest.net` to test my speed, and at first I had above 75 MB speed, which was the usual speed I had before the problem, but when I test my speed again, it shows 60-65 MB again.

I use a Macbook Pro mid 2009 and I have this problem in Mac and in Windows 7.

I also use an Apple TV for streaming and since this problem appeared everything I watch lost its HD quality and usually the stream freezes.
All of the speed test were done only with my laptop on.

Anyone has an idea what else to do to fix my problem ?

Comment: This can be anything from being the router to another factor. How many devices are connected through the router? Have you tried connecting only your laptop to the router by cable, disable wifi and connect the router to the modem?

Comment: If I am connected trough WIFI or through cable directly in the router I have the same problem, same low speed. Only my laptop was connected.

Comment: But have you tested by verifying that your laptop is the ONLY device connected? This is important.

Comment: Yes, my tests were done only with the laptop connected.

Comment: Odd problem, should not happen, which means something inside the router can be faulty. I'd recommend for now to update the firmware of the router.

Comment: The firmware is updated to the latest version. Still the problems persists.

Comment: How old is your router? Could you send it back to the manufacturer as RMA?

Comment: 4-5 months old. I had hope is not a hardware issue, but who knows.

Comment: I'd contact the store you bought it from and tell them the speeds are below what is acceptable, and ask them if it can be sent as RMA

Comment: Yes, I can do that.

Comment: What's your router's hardware version? Early WR841N's peaked at around 66MBps. Also, you should correct your units. You say "MB" in a lot of places where I think you mean Mbps, but it's hard to be sure. (MB/s is a different unit, and MB is definitely not what you want.)

Comment: Maybe you use the router in a too hot , cold climate , some hardware could be broken for somehow.

Comment: David Schwartz: My bad, I meant Mbps. This is my hardware version: WR841N v8 00000000. I had constantly had about 75 Mbps speed on WiFi, but for some reason something happened and the speed dropped.

Comment: I just keep in the other room, it was next to a wall, but didn't have problem with this in the past, now I move it into a central position of the room and the behaviour is the same.